# SVG Animations Very Laggy after Resizing (Expert)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, cross-browser

So I am adding an SVG to my website. I am also resizing this svg to fit most of my screen, by changing a class called **"background-svg"** that you'll see in my code below.

Basically, If you make the SVG bigger, it becomes super laggy (like its animations are super laggy) and even other animations on the page become super laggy. [Try On JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u62h0xzf/2/embedded/)

If you make the SVG small, the animations are Smooth. On the JSFIDDLE link above, try making your window smaller (you'll see the animations are better), then make your window bigger (laggy animations again).

**Problem Only Occurs on Chrome and Safari...No Lags on FireFox**

My SVG:

```
<svg class="background-svg"  viewBox="0 0 400 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
     <filter x="" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="10" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.095 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetInner1"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" in="shadowOffsetInner1" result="shadowBlurInner1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feComposite in="shadowBlurInner1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" result="shadowInnerInner1"></feComposite>
        <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.647959184   0 0 0 0 0.549016553   0 0 0 0 0.549016553  0 0 0 0.35 0" in="shadowInnerInner1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixInner1"></feColorMatrix>
        <feMerge>
           <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
           <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
           <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixInner1"></feMergeNode>
        </feMerge>
     </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">

     <g id="Artboard-1" fill="#8B65E4">
        <path d="M187.785156,200 L180,232 L66,232 L58.2148437,200 L187.785156,200 Z" id="Rectangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <path d="M349.760339,49.1234675 L375.905579,277.733833 L199.999999,277.733834 L43.9648432,143.710938 L349.760339,49.1234675 Z" id="Triangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <path d="M399.8936,96.1889997 L29.4623426,250.140552 L0,36.4302476 L399.8936,96.1889997 Z" id="Triangle-2" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>

     </g>
    <foreignObject x="8%" y="20%" width="80%" height="100%"
           >
           <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                 <h1>
                    Hey! <br />I'm <span>someperson</span> <span class="info">I like</span>
                 </h1>
              </div>
           </body>
        </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

My CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto);
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.background-svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}


h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}
h1 .info {
  display: block;
  color: #CFBDF9;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.box {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}


.box-item {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#Triangle-1 {
  -webkit-animation: box 2.5s infinite; /* Main Anim is super laggy on chrome and safary*/
  -moz-animation: box 2.5s infinite; /* Main Anim seems good on Firefox*/
}

#Triangle-2 { 
  -webkit-animation: box2 1s infinite; /* same as above */
  -moz-animation: box2 1s infinite; /* same as above */
}

@keyframes box2 {
  10% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
  }
}
@keyframes box {
  10% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
}
```

**TL;DR**: Super Laggy SVG Animations if SVG is large, but smooth animations if SVG is small.

Comment: Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. It animates smoothly even at 2000x2000 pixels.

Comment: that's really weird. What laptop do you have? I'm running OSX on latest MacBook Pro and it looks like this (note this is the guy's answer below, but mine lags exactly the same). [Streamable Link](https://streamable.com/0lc6)

Comment: ^You can see above that in a small screen, it doesn't lag at all. In a somewhat larger window, it lags a bit more and in a really big window where SVG is much larger, it really lags badly.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with GPU usage when animating with pure CSS. Although most properties like transform are 'GPU injected' this isn't a guarantee. If you were to do this with JavaScript; you may see significant performance enhancements.

I do not get much 'lag' at all while running these animations.

This article is specific to a JS animation library, but clearly explains this concept as well.

[How CSS animations are rendered](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)

As far as performance changing with window scaling, it has to do with the number of pixels being altered/rendered with each animation cycle.

For example, if you're vector SVG draws a shape on a 500x500px canvas that takes up 75% of the area, you're going to be drawing alot less pixels in then if you have a 2000x2000px canvas with a shape that takes up 75% of the area.

Since this is calculated over and over again then redrawn when you're using an SVG, there can be a significant performance difference when scaling up.

Since browsers are built and render differently, FireFox is simply able to handle the redrawing of these shapes over and over better than the other browsers in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed two main issues:

- the order of the css properties: transform and transition properties are after the vendor-specific ones, so I put it before them
- the use of the 2D transformations, which don't exploit hardware acceleration, so I changed them with the equivalent 3D ones

The following snippet contains part of what I've modified, you can try it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dyxLs0u/2/) and give me a feedback

```
#Triangle-2 {
    animation: box2 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: box2 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: box2 1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: box2 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes box2 {
    10% {
        transform: rotate(1deg);
        -o-animation: rotateZ(1deg);
        -moz-animation: rotateZ(1deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    }
    90% {
        transform: rotate(-2deg);
        -o-animation: rotateZ(-2deg);
        -moz-animation: rotateZ(-2deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
    }
}
```

I've worked with html elements translations in the past, and in my case the 3D css solution outperformed the 2D and the javascript ones, mostly because of the hardware speed up without passing through the javascript interpreter.
If you want take a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/weighing-svg-animation-techniques-benchmarks/) to have more details about hardware accelerations and comparison with javascript solutions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem still persists though. Here is a [streamable link](https://streamable.com/0lc6) for your JSFiddle. Does it lag similarly on your laptop as well?